# perltex to globally use strict

Tags: perl, latex

To enforce clean and explicit code, I customarily

```
use strict;
```

when programming Perl.
I would like to keep this habit in **perltex**, too.

So where should I put this `use strict;` statement so that it governs all successive `\perldo`, `\perlnewcommand`, `\perlnewenvironment`, `\perlrenewcommand` and `\perlrenewenvironment` invocations in the perltex input file?

The following perltex example file runs without raising an error:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{perltex}

    \perldo{
        my $scalar = "ok";
        our @array = qw( array is fine );
        %HASH = (
            subject => "hash",
            result => "perfect"
        );
        use strict;
    }

    \perlnewcommand\printscalar{
        return $scalar;
    }

    \perlnewcommand\printarray{
        return join ", ", @array;
    }

    \perlnewcommand\printhash{
        return join ", ", map { sprintf "%s = %s", $_, $HASH{$_} } keys %HASH;
    }

\begin{document}
    Scalar: \printscalar

    Array: \printarray

    Hash: \printhash
\end{document}
```

It produces something similar to

> [image: typeset output text]

That no error is raised shows that `use strict;` in the top `\perldo` argument is disregarded in the definition of `\printscalar`. The result also shows that the setting of `$scalar` was not known there any more because of the `my`. To avoid such mistakes, I would wish to receive an error

> Global symbol "$scalar" requires explicit package name

whenever I forget to specify `my` or `our` when introducing a new variable.

A workaround to my problem is to include the statement

```
use strict;
```

in all `\perldo`, ... commands, and this can be done using macros. Nevertheless I wonder whether there is no possibility to avoid such re-statements.

Comment: No, `env PERL5OPT=w perltex --nosafe perlhash.tex` does not help; it runs without raising the desired error when given the above file as perlhash.tex.

Comment: `env PERLOPT=-Mstrict perltex --nosafe perlhash.tex` runs without flagging any error, too.

Comment: `env PERL5OPT=-Mstrict perltex --nosafe perlhash.tex` raises the desired error (and in fact also rejects the declaration of %HASH). So it is a possible solution to my problem as stated. The question remains whether this is not possible inside the perltex source file so that the applicability of `use strict` can be adjusted.

Answer (score 1):

The [perltex CTAN documentation](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/perltex/perltex.pdf) gives in section **3.2.3** a list of the loaded modules and pragmas.  These *include* `use strict;`.

The docs are a little unclear on when this is the default, but it appears to be under `--nosafe`. Then this option should be the way to toggle it and get those defaults loaded.

Did you try setting it only in the first command used (like `\perldo`)?  That may well be enough.

The `--permit` option allows "features" described in [Opcode](http://perldoc.perl.org/Opcode.html) module to be specified, what is done using the module [Safe](http://perldoc.perl.org/Safe.html). While I don't see how to directly make use of this, the discussion under `Safe::reval` method may be helpful.

I don't have the module installed here and can't try. I hope that this is of some use.

As the final resort, why not contact the author?  You may have revealed a bug (in documentation), since the observed behavior seems to conflict the docs.  Also, this may well be feasible to add.

Comment: Thanks, as far as I understand, --nosafe and the module Safe are concerned with sandboxing, I would not see how this should impact `use strict`.

Comment: @BernhardBodenstorfer It stands to reason that it loads that list depending on whether it is setting up a sandbox or not. Unfortunately, that is unclear in the docs -- it appears to say that those _are loaded_ (period), but you say you get it otherwise.  The next thing then is that it may mean that they are loaded in one case, but not in the other (an you get that one).  I can't try now :(

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Unfortunately, it turns out that if I omit the `use strict` statement in my above perltex input and drop the --nosafe option from the command line, still no error is flagged. So `use strict` does not appear to be in force regardless of the option --nosafe.

Comment: @BernhardBodenstorfer  In particular, the list includes `Getopt::Long`, and this should be always available, and so then `use strict;` should be, too.  It is a little confusing.

Comment: @BernhardBodenstorfer  I see. That behavior seems to conflict the **3.2.3** section in the docs (unless I'm misreading it somehow).  Perhaps contact the author? You may have revealed a bug.  Also, this strikes me as something that is feasible to add as a global option of some sort.